# Pop to Pod communication for pods within the same Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes deployment that has 3 replicas. It starts 3 pods which are distributed across a given cluster. I would like to know how to reliably get one pod to contact another pod within the same `ReplicaSet`.

The deployment above is already wrapped up in a Kubernetes `Service`. But `Services` do not cover my use case. I need each instance of my container (each `Pod`) to start-up a local in memory cache and have these cache communicate/sync with other cache instances running on other `Pods`. This is how I see a simple distributed cache working on for my service. Pod to pod communication within the same cluster is allowed as per the [Kubernetes Network Model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) but I cannot see a reliable way to address each a pod from another pod.

I believe I can use a `StatefulSet`, however, I don't want to lose the `ClusterIP` assigned to the service which is required by `Ingress` for load balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you can use statefulset, and ingress doesn't need ClusterIP that assigned to the service, since it uses the endpoints, so 'headless service' is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know that Ingress directly communicates with endpoints. What if there is later another object added to the entire deployment chain that does require a cluster IP?

Comment: also, could you please explain to me what the following line from [Services document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for headless services mean: `Sometimes you don’t need or want load-balancing`?

Comment: In case of requiring a cluster ip, we can create a new service to handle that. About 'don't need load-balancing', that means no iptable-level load-balancing, while the service name can be resolved to A records that points directly to the Pods backing the service,  so a DNS-level load-balancing is still working.